# How does the seasonal component of Seasonal ARIMA work?

Tags: algorithm, time-series, forecasting, arima

I understood ARIMA but I have an issue with the seasonal component. Imagine we have daily data with weekly seasonality as shown in the screenshot.

If I fit an ARIMA`(3,0,3)(3,0,3)7` and try to predict the point at `t(36)`, then the non-seasonal components will use the red-marked values:

[image: Image without seasonal compoenents]

But regarding the seasonal component, will it go back 7 steps and then use 3 values (because `P` and `Q` are set to 3) and therefore use all the green marked values? Or is it going to simply use the last 3 points at `t-7`, `t-14`, and `t-21` marked in orange (ignoring `t-28`)?:

[image: Image with seasonal compnents]

Comment: Offtopic: @Arne: I see you deleted [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69000105/16343464), it was a good answer, just a tiny mistake. Don't hesitate to restore it, I'd be happy to upvote ;)

Comment: Thank you @mozway, I undeleted it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it our myself, in case someone cares:
It is going to use the last 3 points at `t-7`, `t-14`, and `t-21` marked in orange, ignoring `t-28`.