# pandas/python: filter by condition within same column grouping

Tags: python, pandas, filter

i have a df that has multiple pairs of related items; example: fxr_dl2_rank.r1 and fxr_dl2_rank.r1_wp. Is it possible to fliter all the related pairs with both positive results?

```
data = {'item':['fxr_dl2_rank.r1','fxr_dl2_rank.r2','fxr_dl2_rank.r3',
                'fxr_dl2_rank.r4','fxr_dl2_rank.r5',
                'fxr_dl2_rank.r1_wp','fxr_dl2_rank.r2_wp','fxr_dl2_rank.r3_wp',
                'fxr_dl2_rank.r4_wp','fxr_dl2_rank.r5_wp',],
'result':[-0.15,0.13,-0.29,0.18,-0.18,0.00,0.16,0.15,0.17,-0.17]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First rework the 'item' to get the common part, use it to group the rows, check whether all elements are positive and use the output for slicing:

```
group = df['item'].str.replace('_wp$', '', regex=True)
df[df.groupby(group)['result'].transform(lambda s: all(s.ge(0)))]
```

output:

```
                 item  result
1     fxr_dl2_rank.r2    0.13
3     fxr_dl2_rank.r4    0.18
6  fxr_dl2_rank.r2_wp    0.16
8  fxr_dl2_rank.r4_wp    0.17
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
#create helper column
df["helper"] = df["item"].str[:15]
#filter out all negative values in result
df = df[df["result"] >= 0]

#keep only duplicated rows in helper column
df[df.duplicated(subset="helper", keep=False)]
```